# Recursions done right

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a function which should return a list of 6 elements. It should take an empty array, a 'mode', which has to be 'add' here, and a third parameter which is the number the subsequent element should be incremented by (compared to the element before).
For example the returned array could be something like

```
[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

http://jsbin.com/vuvunotifu/edit?js,console

I tested this on JsBin, however there seems to be a stackoverflow (no pun intended) in the last if-block. Not sure why. Does someone know how to solve this?

```
  function getRandomInt(max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}


function getSequence(array, mode, differBy){
  if(mode === 'add'){
    if (array.length >= 6){
      return array;
    }
    if (array.length === 0){
      array.push(getRandomInt(getRandomInt(20)));
      getSequence(array, 'add', getRandomInt(2) + 1);
      console.log(array)
    }
    if (array.length <= 5){
      let arrayCopy = array;
      let lastInArray = arrayCopy.pop();
      array.push(lastInArray + differBy);
      getSequence(array, 'add', differBy);
    }
  }
}

console.log(getSequence([], 'add'));
```

Comment: I don't get a stackoverflow in either jsbin or just pasting it from jsbin into a console. The jsbin code and your inline example are not the same

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are not making a copy of the array - you are just (basically) setting up another reference to the same array.  So the `arrayCopy.pop()` also changes what the variable `array` sees, which makes it so `array` never grows.

To correct your code (keeping it as close as possible to what it is), you could use `array.slice()` to make an actual copy of the data.

Or, the simpler solution is to set `lastInArray` using `array.slice(-1)`.

See

https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600

and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0):

`let arrayCopy = array;` is not actually copying the array so when you pop an item, it's just gone from the original array. The array does not increase in length at all. You need to not pop the item at all.

```
function getSequence(array, mode, differBy){
  if(mode === 'add'){
    if (array.length >= 6){
      return array;
    }
     if (array.length === 0){
       array.push(getRandomInt(getRandomInt(20)));
       getSequence(array, 'add', getRandomInt(2) + 1);
       console.log(array)
    }
    if (array.length <= 5){      
      let lastInArray = array[array.length-1];
      array.push(lastInArray + differBy);
      getSequence(array, 'add', differBy);
    }
  }
}

getSequence([], 'add');
```

Comment: Right. Just a follow-up: now I'm in the first if-block and the array has a length of 6 and you can see that with a console log, that the array looks fine there. But when returned, it's undefined. How can that be?

Comment: A return has to be added to the other ifs as well.

Comment: @working4themiddleclass the return is not actually necessary. You are passing an array reference so you can use that. Your initial call should be `var array = []; getSequence(array, 'add')` and then `array` will have the correct data. If you are going to use the array as an accumulator then you shouldn't really be returning it

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code you shared is at `let arrayCopy = array;`, here it isn't creating a new array, but making the `arrayCopy` reference to the same array, so when you `pop()` this one, it `pop()` the other one too.

To create a new array with the copy of the other you should use `array.slice()`. changing that seems to make your code work.